# Maven is unable to resolve class testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIException

Tags: java, maven, testing, build, soapui

I am running a SOAP UI project through maven using the eviware maven-soapui-plugin and I am getting some unresolved class for TestLink.

I believe that soapui is configured to update TestLink automatically upon running but when executing I am getting unresolved class for a couple of classes.

```
Script1.groovy: 8: unable to resolve class Iconstantes 
 @ line 8, column 1.
   public final class TestLinkUpdate implements Iconstantes 


Script1.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIException
 @ line 4, column 1.
   import testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIException;
```

I have added this dependency to my pom.xml file but that did not change anything:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.eti.kinoshita</groupId>
        <artifactId>testlink-java-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.6-1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Anyone has an idea if it is a plugin configuration thing or if I have to add more dependencies?

Comment: Not sure whether that version exists... Check here:
http://grepcode.com/project/repo1.maven.org/maven2/br.eti.kinoshita/testlink-java-api/

Comment: Thats weird! I just tried with 1.9.4-0 which from your link is the latest stable release and I am getting the same exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add the dependency to the `<plugin>` instead of `<project>`

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>...</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>...</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>br.eti.kinoshita</groupId>
                    <artifactId>testlink-java-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.6-1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
```

Comment: That looked right to me but i am still getting the same exceptions